# What is the fastest way to append writes of 4KB to a file?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, latency, throughput

What is the fastest way to append 4KB writes to a file ?

I tried concurrently writing 4KB from multiple threads with each thread tracking its offset in file. No data is corrupted or writes are lost. But 4 writer threads are slower than 1 writer thread. Disk utilization is also not different.

I then tried writes on a preallocated file which already has 4 GB data and then writing to it. Single writer thread is faster than appending to empty file. Even in preallocated case, 4 writer threads are slower than 1 writer thread.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

void write_concurrently(string filename, const int data_in_gb, const int num_threads, const char start_char,
    bool stream_cache = true) {
    const int offset = 4 * 1024;
    const long long num_records_each_thread = (data_in_gb * 1024 * ((1024 * 1024)/ (num_threads * offset)));

    {
        auto write_file_fn = [&](int index) {
            // each thread has its own handle
            fstream file_handle(filename, fstream::in  | fstream::out | fstream::ate | fstream::binary);
            if (!stream_cache) {
                file_handle.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0); // no bufferring in fstream
            }

            file_handle.seekp(0, ios_base::beg);

            vector<char> data(offset, (char)(index + start_char));
            long long myoffset = index * offset;

            for (long long i = 0; i < num_records_each_thread; ++i) {
                file_handle.seekp(myoffset, ios_base::beg);
                file_handle.write(data.data(), offset);
                myoffset += num_threads * offset;
            }

            // file_handle.flush();
        };

        auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        vector<thread> writer_threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
            writer_threads.push_back(std::thread(write_file_fn, i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
            writer_threads[i].join();
        }

        auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << "Data written : " << data_in_gb << " GB, " << num_threads << " threads " 
            << ", cache " << (stream_cache ? "true " : "false ") << ", size " << offset << " bytes ";
        std::cout << "Time taken: " << (end_time - start_time).count() / 1000 << " micro-secs" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        ifstream file(filename, fstream::in | fstream::binary);
        file.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
        EXPECT_EQ(num_records_each_thread * num_threads * offset, file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
        EXPECT_TRUE(file);

        char data[offset]{ 0 };
        for (long long i = 0; i < (num_records_each_thread * num_threads); ++i) {
            file.read(data, offset);
            EXPECT_TRUE(file || file.eof()); // should be able to read until eof
            char expected_char = (char)((i % num_threads) + start_char);

            bool same = true;
            for (auto & c : data) {
                same = same && (c == expected_char);
            }

            EXPECT_TRUE(same);
            if (!same) {
                std::cout << "corruption detected !!!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            if (file.eof()) {
                EXPECT_EQ(num_records_each_thread * num_threads, i + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
// analysis: Possible but multiple thread is slower because of exlsuive locking in filesystem : ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite
//Name                                                          Inc %        Inc    Exc %      Exc  Fold                                 When     First        Last
//module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite >> 11.5       1, 030    11.5    1, 030    3     1o010___110110110___11011011____    63.097  12, 941.694
//+ module ntfs.sys << ntfs!NtfsCopyWriteA >> 7.7        693      0.0        0     0     00000___00000010o___01o10000____    63.097  12, 941.694
//| +module fltmgr.sys << fltmgr!FltpFastIoWrite >> 7.7      693      0.0        0     0     00000___00000010o___01o10000____    63.097  12, 941.694
//| +module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!NtWriteFile >> 7.7      693      0.0        0     0     00000___00000010o___01o10000____    63.097  12, 941.694
//+ module ntfs.sys << ntfs!NtfsFsdWrite >> 3.8      337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
//+ module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!IofCallDriver >> 3.8         337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
//+ module fltmgr.sys << fltmgr!FltpDispatch >> 3.8      337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
//+ module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!NtWriteFile >> 3.8       337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626

TEST(fstream, write_concurrently_to_same_file) {
    string filename = "file4.log";
    long data_in_gb = 4;
    {
        // create file before write threads start.
        {
            fstream file(filename, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc | fstream::binary);
        }
        write_concurrently(filename, data_in_gb, 1, 'A'); // concurrent is slower than 1 thread
    }

    {
        // create file before write threads start.
        {
            fstream file(filename, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc | fstream::binary);
        }
        write_concurrently(filename, data_in_gb, 4, 'A'); // concurrent is slower than 1 thread
    }


    std::remove(filename.c_str());
}

// Preallocated file
TEST(fstream, preallocated_file_concurrent_writes) {
    string filename = "file5.log";
    const int data_in_gb = 4;
    {
        // create file before write threads start.
        fstream file(filename, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc | fstream::binary);
        write_concurrently(filename, data_in_gb, 1, 'A');
    }

    std::cout << "Preallocated file." << std::endl;
    write_concurrently(filename, data_in_gb, 1, 'B');
    write_concurrently(filename, data_in_gb, 4, 'C');

    std::remove(filename.c_str());
}
```

Runs with release mode, visual studio 2017 msvc compiler. Code above is cross platform.

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
Note: Google Test filter = *write_concurrently_to_same_file
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from fstream
[ RUN      ] fstream.write_concurrently_to_same_file
Data written : 4 GB, 1 threads , cache true , size 4096 bytes Time taken: 21895907 micro-secs
Data written : 4 GB, 4 threads , cache true , size 4096 bytes Time taken: 30937922 micro-secs
[       OK ] fstream.write_concurrently_to_same_file (84657 ms)
[----------] 1 test from fstream (84658 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (84660 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.


>.\x64\Release\tests.exe --gtest_filter=*preallocated_file_concurrent_writes
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
Note: Google Test filter = *preallocated_file_concurrent_writes
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from fstream
[ RUN      ] fstream.preallocated_file_concurrent_writes
Data written : 4 GB, 1 threads , cache true , size 4096 bytes Time taken: 20529264 micro-secs
Preallocated file.
Data written : 4 GB, 1 threads , cache true , size 4096 bytes Time taken: 15053958 micro-secs
Data written : 4 GB, 4 threads , cache true , size 4096 bytes Time taken: 16394996 micro-secs
[       OK ] fstream.preallocated_file_concurrent_writes (87653 ms)
[----------] 1 test from fstream (87654 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (87659 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

I looked at profile and one difference i noticed was lock acquire fn showing up in filesystem in multi threads case.

```
// analysis: multiple threads are slower because of exlsuive locking in filesystem : ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite
//Name                                                          Inc %        Inc    Exc %      Exc  Fold                                 When     First        Last
//module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite >> 11.5       1, 030    11.5    1, 030    3     1o010___110110110___11011011____    63.097  12, 941.694
//+ module ntfs.sys << ntfs!NtfsCopyWriteA >> 7.7        693      0.0        0     0     00000___00000010o___01o10000____    63.097  12, 941.694
//| +module fltmgr.sys << fltmgr!FltpFastIoWrite >> 7.7      693      0.0        0     0     00000___00000010o___01o10000____    63.097  12, 941.694
//| +module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!NtWriteFile >> 7.7      693      0.0        0     0     00000___00000010o___01o10000____    63.097  12, 941.694
//+ module ntfs.sys << ntfs!NtfsFsdWrite >> 3.8      337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
//+ module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!IofCallDriver >> 3.8         337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
//+ module fltmgr.sys << fltmgr!FltpDispatch >> 3.8      337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
//+ module ntoskrnl << ntoskrnl!NtWriteFile >> 3.8       337      0.0        0     0     o0000___00o00o00o___00o00o00____    68.759  12, 912.626
```

Current test runs are in windows.

Comment: No compiler or version mentioned, no mention of whether you built an optimized version of the program, ...

Comment: it is release mode, visual studio msvc comiler

Comment: Which version of the Visual Studio compiler?  All of these details should be mentioned in the original post.

Comment: edited post.. thanks for pointing out

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be limited by the performance of the disk IO system.  I doubt adding threads is going to have any benefit here.

Comment: I'm with @G.M. - You'll find that it's enough with _one_ thread to use the max speed of your disk - even if it's a SSD.

Comment: With NVMe disks the limit could also be memory bandwidth.

Comment: You mean `kiB`, not `kB`, let alone `KB`. ;)

Comment: @G.M. the disk utilization that I see in task manager is less than 15% in both single and multi thread case.